# Filtering fetched data

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, filter

I have an object of filters.

```
filters = {color: 'black', size: '40'}
```

i want to return a filtered array of my data. Here's a sample of my data:

```
data = [  
  { 
    id: 1,
    name: "Good Engine001"
    categories: ['machine'],
    color: ['Black', 'white'],
    size: [30, 40, 50]
  },
  

{ 
    id: 2,
    name: "Good Plane"
    categories: ['machine', 'plane'],
    color: ['Grey', 'white'],
    size: [10, 30, 50]
  },

{ 
    id: 3,
    name: "Good Chair001"
    categories: ['furniture', 'chair'],
    color: ['Brown', 'Black'],
    size: [3, 5, 40]
  }
];
```

```
filteredProducts = data.filter((item) =>
    Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
        item[key].includes(value)
    )
```

I'm quite stuck here. I am trying to set the filtered products to be equal to the few entries that matches with the values provided in my filters object. what am i doing wrong?

I was expecting this:

```
filteredProducts = [
        
{ 
    id: 1,
    name: "Good Engine001"
    categories: ['machine'],
    color: ['Black', 'white'],
    size: [30, 40, 50]
  },


{ 
    id: 3,
    name: "Good Chair001"
    categories: ['furniture', 'chair'],
    color: ['Brown', 'Black'],
    size: [3, 5, 40]
  }

];
```

But i got the same data.

Comment: Your arrays aren't valid javascript.

Comment: You probable want an array of Objects [{},{}], but you have an array of arrays [[].[]] which wont work

Comment: Why is your filter `color` all lowercase but the values in your data are all capitalised? Why is the filter `size` a string?

Comment: You're missing commas after each `name` value so your data is still invalid JS

Comment: With the minor typos fixes, your code works as expected ~ https://jsfiddle.net/16dk4xm5/. It returns an empty array because none of your `color` properties contain `"black"` or the string `"40"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your contributions. After a few days of racking by brain; I came up with a solution.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Good Engine001",
    categories: "machine",
    color: ["Black", "white"],
    size: [30, 40, 50]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Good Plane",
    categories: "machine",
    color: ["Grey", "white"],
    size: [10, 30, 50]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Good Chair001",
    categories: "chair",
    color: ["Brown", "Black"],
    size: [3, 5, 40]
  }
];

function App() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({ color: "", size: "" });
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = data.filter((item) =>
      Object.entries(filters).every(
        ([key, value]) => !value || item[key].includes(value)
      )
    );
    setFilteredData(filtered);
  }, [filters]);

  const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFilters((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Color:
        <select name="color" value={filters.color} onChange={handleFilterChange}>
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option value="Black">Black</option>
          <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
          <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        Size:
        <select name="size" value={filters.size} onChange={handleFilterChange} >
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <ul>
        {filteredData.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here's what I figured out:

- react state will work better with this as it re-renders the application when the state changes.
- The Object.entries function that i started with just needed a little tweaks. I had to make it such that when no value is selected, the whole array is being rendered; but when there is a value, then the filtered objects are being rendered.
- The handleFilterChange helps to modify the filters object. It's working fine now; thanks a bunch guys.

I'm sorry for the typos that I had in the question; I'm new here, hopefully I'll get better @ asking and answering questions.

**Thanks a bunch once again.**

*I'm sorry; i had a hard time testing it here; not sure how to import react hooks on the editor*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare case-insensitively and loosely compare numbers to their string equivalents, you won't be able to use `Array.prototype.includes()` since it uses strict comparisons.

Instead, you'll need to use `Array.prototype.some()` and compare stringified values using [*base* sensitivity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#sensitivity)...

```js
// Your data with typos fixed and minified
const data = [{"id":1,"name":"Good Engine001","categories":["machine"],"color":["Black","white"],"size":[30,40,50]},{"id":2,"name":"Good Plane","categories":["machine","plane"],"color":["Grey","white"],"size":[10,30,50]},{"id":3,"name":"Good Chair001","categories":["furniture","chair"],"color":["Brown","Black"],"size":[3,5,40]}]

// Stringifies values and compares with "base" sensitivity
const comparator = (dataValue, filterValue) =>
  dataValue
    .toString()
    .localeCompare(filterValue, undefined, { sensitivity: "base" }) === 0;

// Checks various data types using the above comparator
const predicate = (dataValue, filterValue) => {
  // Check arrays
  if (Array.isArray(dataValue)) {
    return dataValue.some((value) => comparator(value, filterValue));
  }

  // Exclude nested objects and null
  if (typeof dataValue !== "object") {
    return comparator(dataValue, filterValue);
  }

  return false;
};

const filters = { color: "black", size: "40" };

const filteredProducts = data.filter((item) =>
  Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => predicate(item[key], value))
);

console.log(filteredProducts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score -2):

color names are capital in data while they are not in filter.
'40' is string literal in filter, while it is number in your data.
and also your data should be like this with curly braces around each item:

```
const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Good Engine001",
        categories: ['machine'],
        color: ['Black', 'white'],
        size: [30, 40, 50]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Good Plane",
        categories: ['machine', 'plane'],
        color: ['Grey', 'white'],
        size: [10, 30, 50]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Good Chair001",
        categories: ['furniture', 'chair'],
        color: ['Brown', 'Black'],
        size: [3, 5, 40]
      }
    ];
```

Comment: The data is an array of arrays. It is fetched from the backend server. But not withstanding, how do i implement the filter function well? @Vahid18u

Comment: We don't have arrays with key in javascript, and It gives syntax error when you write something like this : cont x = [id:1, ...] . Where have you copied this from?